# Displaylink USB show "Logo / Loading" on monitor

Tags: 12.04, drivers, display, displaylink

I tried with this problem for 2 years already. LOL, today, I install Ubuntu for I have to resolve it or I will back to stupid Windows 7.

First, I have 3 monitors. My graphic card is support dual ( ATI Radeon ), so I have no problem on extend those multi monitor on VGA and DVI.

The 3rd monitor is Displaylink USB. 
After installed everything required, when I reboot, the displaylink monitor show "Ubuntu ...." like logo / loading screen.

I go to System > Display , Detect monitor, it only show my 1st and 2nd, NO 3RD Displaylink.

I can move my mouse between those 1st & 2nd, but the 3rd is only show the Ubuntu Screen.

I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, then screen switch to Displaylink USB 3RD monitor, but its "Terminal" not a desktop.

Then I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> , the screen switch back to my 1st, 2nd, and the displaylink 3rd is witch back to Logo / Ubuntu again.

This is my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` :

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "DisplayLinkScreen" Leftof "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
    Load  "dri2"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "dri"
    Load  "record"
    Load  "extmod"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection


Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "DisplayLinkMonitor"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP1"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1680x1050"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-CRT2"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "1680 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"

        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Dac6Bit"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Dac8Bit"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "BusType"               # [<str>]
        #Option     "CPPIOMode"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "CPusecTimeout"         # <i>
        #Option     "AGPMode"               # <i>
        #Option     "AGPFastWrite"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AGPSize"               # <i>
        #Option     "GARTSize"              # <i>
        #Option     "RingSize"              # <i>
        #Option     "BufferSize"            # <i>
        #Option     "EnableDepthMoves"      # [<bool>]
        #Option     "EnablePageFlip"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoBackBuffer"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DMAForXv"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "FBTexPercent"          # <i>
        #Option     "DepthBits"             # <i>
        #Option     "PCIAPERSize"           # <i>
        #Option     "AccelDFS"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "IgnoreEDID"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "CustomEDID"            # [<str>]
        #Option     "DisplayPriority"       # [<str>]
        #Option     "PanelSize"             # [<str>]
        #Option     "ForceMinDotClock"      # <freq>
        #Option     "ColorTiling"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "RageTheatreCrystal"    # <i>
        #Option     "RageTheatreTunerPort"  # <i>
        #Option     "RageTheatreCompositePort"  # <i>
        #Option     "RageTheatreSVideoPort"     # <i>
        #Option     "TunerType"             # <i>
        #Option     "RageTheatreMicrocPath"     # <str>
        #Option     "RageTheatreMicrocType"     # <str>
        #Option     "ScalerWidth"           # <i>
        #Option     "RenderAccel"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SubPixelOrder"         # [<str>]
        #Option     "ClockGating"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VGAAccess"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ReverseDDC"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "LVDSProbePLL"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ConnectorTable"        # <str>
        #Option     "DefaultConnectorTable"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DefaultTMDSPLL"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TVDACLoadDetect"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ForceTVOut"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TVStandard"            # <str>
        #Option     "IgnoreLidStatus"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DefaultTVDACAdj"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Int10"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "EXAVSync"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ATOMTVOut"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "R4xxATOM"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ForceLowPowerMode"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DynamicPM"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NewPLL"                # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "radeon"
    BusID       "PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"

        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Rotate"                # <str>
        #Option     "fbdev"                 # <str>
        #Option     "debug"                 # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "fbdev"
    BusID       "PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"

        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DefaultRefresh"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ModeSetClearScreen"    # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card2"
    Driver      "vesa"
    BusID       "PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP1" "0-DFP1"
    Option      "Monitor-CRT2" "0-CRT2"
    BusID       "PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DisplayLinkDevice"
    Driver      "displaylink"
    Option      "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
    Option "ShadowFB" "off"
EndSection


Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Virtual   3600 1920
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "DisplayLinkScreen"
    Device     "DisplayLinkDevice"
    Monitor    "DisplayLinkMonitor"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"        
        Depth     24
        Modes    "1920x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions:

First, ensure that the DisplayLink driver is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-displaylink
```

Reboot and regenerate your xorg.conf--or try it without one; X is fairly decent at autoconfiguring.  At any rate, it looks like X is detecting it in some capacity (unless you hand-wrote that xorg.conf), so the driver is probably already installed.

My second suggestion:  Read through [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1870620) and see if you can get any joy using those tips.  The only part that looks substantially different from your setup is the part about "add[ing] the following to /etc/gdm/Init/Default above the "exit 0" at the end of the file:"

```
### set display for attached USB devices
XRANDR=`gdmwhich xrandr`
if [ "x$XRANDR" != "x" ] ; then
$XRANDR -o 0
fi
```

Finally, look through your X logs; sometimes (!) useful info can be gleaned from them.  Or post them here; I'd be happy to take a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to specify

```
Option "Xinerama" "Off"
```

in your `ServerLayout` section. This would prevent you dragging windows between the monitors, but might help.

You may also want to try reducing your `Depth` to 16 from 24.

Finally, you could try using the `fbdev` driver for your Radeon as well - this would seriously reduce the performance of this card.

Make sure you make backups of your xorg.conf before you make any changes at all.